# Getting input-prompts in unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity. I want to get a Prompt asking some question and a textfield to store the answer set by the user.

I searched online but no proper answers are there.

I am writing my scripts in c#.

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out :

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour {
        void Start ()
        {
            var input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
            var se= new InputField.SubmitEvent();
            se.AddListener(SubmitName);
            input.onEndEdit = se;

            //or simply use the line below, 
            //input.onEndEdit.AddListener(SubmitName);  // This also works
        }

        private void SubmitName(string arg0)
        {
            // Store the user answer here                
             Debug.Log(arg0);
        }

}
```

Simply add the script to a gameobject in your scene that has a InputField component attached to it and you are good to go.